# React JS- API is taking longer to load

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

[image]I have a React application where i see my one particular API is taking 6.15sec to load. I see this timing in my network tab under Time in my Chrome browser. However, when i check the time taken by API in backend, it's only 5S. I am not able to figure out from where does the additional delay is getting added.

Anyone has got any idea around this. Any help is much appreciated.